# Restore procedure to create Linux machine

Tags: linux, restore

I get the following files (that was backup from some Linux machine )

```
 swap.label
 sda-partition-info.sfdisk
 sda.mbr
 sda1.fsa
 sda2.fsa
 sda3.fsa
 sda.labels
 sda7.fsa
 sda5.fsa
```

can some one advice how to perform restore from these files? , in order to build new Linux machine from this files ?

Comment: Which tool was used to perform the backup?

Comment: this was the big question , I don't know -:(

Comment: What is the output of `file sda1.fsa`

Comment: its a big binary file , like tar file

Answer (score 1):

The `.fsa` files seem to be backups generated with Filesystem Archiver for Linux (FSArchiver).

The tool's homage has a [quick start guide](http://www.fsarchiver.org/QuickStart#How_to_extract_filesystems_from_an_archive)

For **example** to restore the partition on `sda1`

```
fsarchiver restfs sda1.fsa id=0,dest=/dev/sda1
```

Comment: what I know is the linux was backup on blade machine HS22

Comment: so if I have empty disk on that machine - then what is the process to restore?

Comment: The file `sda-partition-info.sfdisk` most likely contains the partitioning layout of the disk. You should re-create the same portions and then use fsarchiver to restore them.

Comment: yes thx , but if I have empty disk , so how the process to restore the files on the new disk ( maybe I need to boot from the USB from some linux ) ,??? and from there do something

Comment: so maybe if I boot from linux ( USB ) the on that linux I need to run the fsarchiver restfs sda1.fsa id=0,dest=/dev/sdaX on each partition ?

Comment: so if this true this is all the process , or maybe need to perform some other things in order to restore the files on the empty disk